# op_return regex search

Tags: transactions, bitcoind

Is there a webservice around that allows one to search the OP_RETURN data on the blockchain? More precisely: I'm looking for a service that would return the transaction ids of transactions that contain an OP_RETURN with data that matches the given expression.

Answer (score 1):

[Chain.com](http://chain.com/docs) offers OP_RETURN data for addresses, transactions and blocks.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @cdecker: This post seems to be providing a matching though brief answer to the question. I'd say rather the question is at fault than the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Coin Secrets API](http://api.coinsecrets.org/) to obtain the OP_RETURN transactions in each block though it does not yet have a regex feature.